# Javascript says two strings are equal but they are not equal

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have faced with the weird behavior where comparison says that two strings are equal when they are obviously not equal: AngularJS project, I am injecting to config some property via *"@@propertyName"*:

```
states = '@@states'
```

where `"states": []` in another config file.

and lately I want to do the following comparison:

```
if (states === '@@states') {
    states = ''
}
```

Which means that if *states* were not injected - do it an empty string.
Strange behavior here is that even if *states* contain "{}" or "[]" or an array of object it is becomes an empty although values are not equal:

[image: incorrect if]

And it happens only for objects, arrays or array of object, if *states* is a string like "testtest" - comparison works correctly.

I have found a workaround but I'm still interesting in what is going on. Maybe you know it and can explain it. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Comment: Looks interesting but I'm missing more context. Can you provide steps to reproduce this outside your project?

Comment: Perhaps it's some kind of async function...

Comment: @MátéSafranka, it is funny, but it can be reproduced only in the scope of project, I cannot reproduce it outside. I even set a breakpoint at the 'if' statement, put this comparison to the Chrome console on the same page and it works perfectly. But in project it fails.

Comment: When you say "I am injecting to config some property via "@@propertyName" what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Check how many times the if statement runs.

Comment: @Yftach, I mean grunt-replace. It replaces properties in one file with the values from another file.

Comment: @Craig, exactly 1 time.

Comment: Try to log to console the states variable to see in runtime what is in it